# How do you retrieve a pointer to the active workbook In a vb .net excel document customization (not add in)

Tags: vb.net, excel, visual-studio

I am new to VB.net and am moving an app from VBA. I want to use the document customization model, but can't for the life of me find a way to retreive a pointer to the workbook that is hosting the customization. I have tried

```
dim wb as workbook = Me.Workbook
dim wb as workbook = thisWorkBook
dim wb as workbook = ThisApplication.workbook
```

etc. I only need this in order to be able to select worksheets in the customization so if there is anotherway to do that then that would answer my question too. For example I want to execute this to get a handle to a specific worksheet.

```
dim ws as worksheet = wb.sheets("My Sheet Name")
```

Apologies for what is clearly a very basic question but I have googled around for about three hours so far with no luck.

Comment: What exactly are you using to interface your VB.Net app with Office? Which libraries?

Comment: Ya excel isn't that great. In either case use an oldb connection to open the the excelwork, then get the table and loop through it to get the sheet name.

Comment: I am using Visual studio and created a project (VSTO) using the excel 2013 and 2016 template.  This in so far as I understand it links the VSTO object directly to the workbook vs an add=ion where it is part of excel per se.  While there is a ThisworkBook object I am unable to get a pointer from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of additional trial and error I came across this solution.

You can access the application workbook through the Globals variable produced by VSTO.  Thus,outside of the class declaration for thisWorkbook -- the following will work:

```
Dim wb as ThisWorkBook
wb = Globals.ThisWorkbook
```

Note that web is not of type Workbook but ThisWorkBook which is an overloaded class defined by Visual Studio in the document customization template.