# Closing the instance of that workbook excel?

Tags: vb.net, vba

I have two excel file instances opened. I want to close one of the instances so that when I go to task manager, there will be no trace of the EXCEL.exe running in the process. I'm having the two excel opened from a userform. I have a button in the excel file to close the excel workbook,

```
=== this is vb.net
public sub openExcel()
        my code.... blah blah blah....
        'open excel
        Dim xlsApp As Excel.Application
        Dim xlsWB As Excel.Workbook
        xlsApp = New Excel.Application
        xlsApp.Visible = True
        xlsWB = xlsApp.Workbooks.Open(c:\myExcelFile.xlsm")
end sub


======= this is vba
ThisWorkbook.Save
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.Quit
```

I'm still getting the EXCEL.exe after closing one of the file.

Comment: Why are you opening a second instance in the first place? It's generally better to get a handle on the active workbook e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34958089/how-do-you-retrieve-a-pointer-to-the-active-workbook-in-a-vb-net-excel-document.

Comment: How would I open both file in just one instance? I'm opening both at the same time.

Comment: I've found `Application.Quit` to be really wonky with Excel objects. For whatever reason, the only way I've been able to get them to terminate, is by identifying the process ID, and terminating it when I'm done with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do this:

```
xlsWB = xlsApp.Workbooks.Open(c:\myExcelFile1.xlsm")
xlsWB = xlsApp.Workbooks.Open(c:\myExcelFile2.xlsm")
```

It should only open 1 instance of Excel (as shown in task manager).

If you do this - it will open 2 instance. So basically just keep track of the first instance and reuse it.

```
xlsApp1 = New Excel.Application   
xlsApp2 = New Excel.Application
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps :

*'------in case you whant to close the original opend workbook.*

=== this is vb.net

```
public sub openExcel()

        Dim NameW As String 
        NameW = ThisWorkbook.name  ' get the name of the opened workbook

        my code.... blah blah blah....
        'open excel
        Dim xlsApp As Excel.Application
        Dim xlsWB As Excel.Workbook
        xlsApp = New Excel.Application
        xlsApp.Visible = True
        xlsWB = xlsApp.Workbooks.Open(c:\myExcelFile.xlsm")

        Workbooks(NameW).Close ' close the workbook


end sub


======= this is vba
ThisWorkbook.Save
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.Quit
```

Else if your active workbook is the one you want to close you can use:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Close
```